# Pyenv not shows all version when used as sudo

Tags: python, centos, pyenv

I installed `3.5.2` and `3.5.3` version using pyenv.

```
# pyenv versions
* system (set by /usr/local/pyenv/version)
  3.5.2
  3.5.3
```

But, when I run this command as `sudo` (not login as `root`) it not gives me all versions.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pyenv versions
* system (set by /root/.pyenv/version)
```

I tried using setting the `PYENV_ROOT` path, but that also not works.

```
$ export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/pyenv/
$ sudo /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv versions
* system (set by /root/.pyenv/version)
```

I already have path set in `.bash_profile` in myuser

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/pyenv/
export PATH="/usr/local/pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Also set in `root` user

```
$ sudo cat /root/.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/pyenv/
export PATH="/usr/local/pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I am using centos

```
$ cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/pyenv/
$ sudo /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv versions
```

This doesn't work because `PYENV_ROOT` won't be passed to the environment in sudo.
Try this:

```
$ sudo PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/pyenv/ /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv versions
```

or this:

```
$ export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/pyenv/
$ sudo -E /usr/local/pyenv/bin/pyenv versions
```

`-E` will make the environment variables pass to pyenv. In the man page of `sudo`:

```
 -E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to
             preserve the environment.

 --preserve-env=list
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to add the comma-separated list of environment variables to those preserved from the user's environment.  The security policy may
             return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

The `.bash_profile` in root doesn't work because `sudo` won't load it in this case. You can refer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228314/sudo-command-doesnt-source-root-bashrc) if you prefer to write the config in `.bash_profile`.